# how to get the exact height of header in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, iphone, jquery-mobile, retina-display

I'm new to JQM and I want to get the exact height of a header, but I can't seem to get it accurately. I need this for an Iphone app which should detect the header's height even on iphone 4 with Retina display (or even IPad).

My current test is:

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="m">
  <div id="hdr" data-role="header">
    <a id="bk" href="index.html" data-role="button">Back</a>
    <div style="margin:0 auto;text-align:center;"><img src="../images/lgo_iph.png" alt="" /></div>
    <a href="index.html" data-role="button">Cancel</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

and I get the height with:

```
$(document).live("pageshow", function(){
 alert($('#hdr').outerHeight(true));
 });
```

which alerts 22, which is not correct as if I substitute the $('#hdr') with $('#bk') I get 28 as height which should be smaller.

Any help?

Thank you.

Comment: You may want to look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988200/how-to-detect-the-height-of-the-content-of-a-div as the first answer has an interesting comment about how the first div may have a fixed height.

Comment: `.outerHeight()` includes `padding`/`margin`/`border`, of which I think `border` is the only one applied by jQuery Mobile to a `<div data-role="header">` element. So using `.outerHeight()` should produce a number at least `2px` greater than the actual height. Have you tried regular old `.height()`?

Comment: @James Black but I don't want to add any extra div to the header, actually when I do the header is screwed up!. I just need the header height as it's calculated by JQM itself after page is shown. I guess this should also vary from iphone and iphone retina screens

Comment: @Jasper yes, but anyway the height isn't correct, it's only 20 instead of 22, it should maybe be the double of that.